# SQL CE: Limiting rows returned in the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

In **SQL Compact Edition 3.5** , note that it is the **Compact Edition** I am talking about- Is there a way to limit the amount of rows to only 2? Something like using LIMIT or TOP. I **really don't want** to use anything with a SqlCEDataReader, or SqlCEResultSet. I want to do all the limiting **in the query**. Is this possible now? I have looked around and it doesn't seem so.

EDIT-

In response to Dave Swersky's request for data and using Min()/Max() on some columns as a means to get the top 2 lines, here is some sample (sterilized) data:

```
Line     Site          Function     Status
1010     Las Vegas     new          4
1020     DC            send         1
1030     Portland      copy         1
1040     SF            copy         1
1050     Portland      copy         1
1060     DC            send         1
```

*There are more columns than this but these are the significant ones.

Sorry for the lack of intuitive data (but the actual data is even less intuitive!), but for security i need to change the data.

So- i need to determine: **what site the record was at in the preceding line to determine where it needs to be picked up.**

The **site** on any given line (**except** the first line with **function = 'new'**) **corresponds to where the item is going next.** So simply grabbing that site off the same line wont tell me where it came from. The status will always be 1 or 4. The 4 corresponds to a where it has been delivered already and so i dont want to include those records in the result. But it might be useful in getting the pickup site.

For this table of data i want the query to return the site corresponding to the line just above the first line with status 1. So- for this it would be Las Vegas.

Comment: Why are you averse to using the resultset and just taking the first 2 rows?

Comment: @ctacke - the reason is kind of complicated, but in a nutshell this is only the itinerary for one item, there are many more items than this and all the sites that coorespond to where an item needs to be currently picked up are read in using this query. I am trying to find a way to limit the amount of sites its finding as valid sites that need something picked up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sql CE 3.5 supports the TOP expression:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb686896.aspx

Comment: @raymond-holmboe - Wow, i feel amazed! I also feel like an idiot- haha. I swear i looked on the internets for a couple hours and there was even tons of places specifically saying the functionality didn't exist and the best way was some other trickery! I wonder when this was introduced? Well, thanks alot regardless- really helps me out. Cheers.

Comment: Hi, yes that is one of the nicest features introduced in 3.5 :) I am glad I posted it, nearly didn't cause it already had some answers from some of the big authorities in here.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on your data... if you have guaranteed-sequential IDs or dates you could use MAX with NOT IN subqueries to return a limited number of rows.  Post some of your schema and I'll try to cook up an example.

Comment: @Dave Swersky - Thats where Im leaning towards- I'll post some table data soon

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need to do, you might be able to execute the full query using a DataReader, and only call it's `.Read()` method twice.

Answer (score 1):

I never found an answer in the query itself.
Is this for a mobile app or is this SQL CE on a desktop?

I don't really have a direct answer for you, but will share what I've observed on my own projects...
My experience in using SQL CE in desktop apps is that there are situations where it's more performant to use your application code to do the filtering. So, if you find yourself writing a convoluted query, you may want to also look at writing the filters in your app code inside of data reader.Read() loop and compare results. I've found cases where this cut operations that were taking a couple of seconds down to sub-second.

I know it's not what you want to do, but I've found that SQL CE requires you optimize things a little differently from when you're running against server. There's no network latency to worry about, so the normal kinds of worries don't manifest.

Comment: @Jim Leonardo - It's a Mobile app- I will look more into the logistics of changing my code around to use something like a data reader. It just, initially at least, sounded like a step backward from where i am currently at. but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Jim Leonardo - Yeah, all adapter options to limit the amount of results weren't really an option, in this very specific case. The main thing is that limiting the rows was something i wanted to do in a subquery and the outer query still needed to be able to handle a dynamic range of results. But thanks again anyways